# Why Chrome console panel Ctrl-[ shortcut doesn't work for me?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

Switching between console panels should be possible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> as per devtools help:

[image]

But it does nothing for me. The same goes for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.

Is it because I'm using french keyboard?
Is it possible to use these shortcuts with a french keyboard?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with `CMD+/`? Comment something in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I just set my keyboard to french on mac and enabled: [image: Enable Cmd + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels]

Now by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (on the french keyboard it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>&</kbd>) it works. Do not actually use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to get the actual number on the french keyboard.

Comment: *Note: I don't actually have a french keyboard, just changed it in my settings. Not sure if this will work. Please let me know if it does*

Comment: Friend, I'm talking about the Inspect element panes not the general tabs of chrome.

Comment: yeah, I was able to change between those the way I mentioned. Just be sure to click into the devtools so your focussed on that

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have an extension that is overriding the shortcuts.

1. Open `chrome://extensions/`
2. Scroll to the bottom, click 'Keyboard shortcuts"
3. Ensure that no shortcuts replicate Chrome defaults. If they do, click the X to remove them.